# add a single data to serializer in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

[image]

I'm writing an API where the user's followers are listed.I also want to send the total number of followers in this API.But the totalFollower field keeps repeating.I only want it sent once. Like that:

```
[
totalFollower:2
followers:
{
    {
        "following": "gizli_takip",
    },
    {
        "following": "herkeseacikvetakip",
    }
}]
```

MY serializer

```
class SerializerUserFollowings(serializers.ModelSerializer):
following = serializers.CharField(source="follower.username")

totalFollower = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
class Meta:
    model  = ModelFollower
    fields = ("following","totalFollower")
```

Comment: you'll need to add separate/nested serializer for `followers`

Comment: With Django REST Framework you can modify the [pagination class to display whatever you like.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

Use a [DRF paginator](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination) on your view, which will give a `count` in the response body:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class YourView(...):
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    ...
```

Alternatively if you are using a viewset or something similar like [ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) you can add the specific data into the response for the list function:

```
class YourView(ListAPIView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return <some query for filtering follows by user>
    
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().list(request, args, kwargs)
        response.data["count"] = self.get_queryset().count()
        return response
```